# PHP error_reporting vs. display_errors

Tags: php, error-handling

Is  `error_reporting(0)` same as  `ini_set('display_errors', 0)`? If not, what is the difference?

I'm also interested in security side of this code? Can I achieve '[so malicious users can't probe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20651810)' with this?

Comment: The only difference is [this](http://in3.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors): "*Although display_errors may be set at runtime (with ini_set()), it won't have any affect if the script has fatal errors. This is because the desired runtime action does not get executed.*".

Comment: @AmalMurali - that's true of both functions.  PHP files are parsed completely before any code in that file is executed, so any function you use to enable error reporting will *not* be executed if there are parse errors in the same file.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

They are NOT the same, but in your use may have the same outcome.

1. `error_reporting` is the level of reporting, NONE through ALL.  This determines what types of errors are reported (E_NOTICE, E_WARNING, E_ALL, etc..).
2. `display_errors` is whether to display those errors (output to browser, CLI, etc...) that are reported from 1.

If you set `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `ini_set('display_errors', '0')` you can still get all errors reported in the log file but not displayed.

With `error_reporting(0)` you don't get any errors displayed or in the log and it doesn't matter the values of `display_errors`.

`display_errors` should be off in your production applications, preferably in `php.ini` so that information such as file paths, database names and usernames are not shown. Error reporting sent to the log is beneficial and should not be a security concern.

Comment: Can I acchive this security task with them?

Comment: You want `display_errors` off in your app or preferably `php.ini`.  Error reporting sent to the log is beneficial and should not be a security concern.